# angular-dashboard-framework give me error Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- adfDashboardDirective

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dashboard

I'm using `angular-dashboard-framework`. Its was working fine in ruby on rails application but when i separated from rails application its give me following error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- adfDashboardDirective
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModal%20%3C-%20adfDashboardDirective

```
at angular.js:68
at angular.js:4284
at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4432)
at angular.js:4289
at getService (angular.js:4432)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4464)
at angular.js:7037
at forEach (angular.js:336)
at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:7035)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4473)
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `adfDashboard` requires [`angular-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), could you try adding this and see if the error is still there ?

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I have less than 15 repu otherwise i will vote up.

Comment: No problem, the answer lies in `$uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- adfDashboardDirective`, if you ever get an error like this just google the stuff in the arrows ;)